# Setting up an “under maintenance” template with Apache .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to know how I can install an under maintenance template to my site. It contains this files and folder:

- index.html
- images (folder)
- tools (folder)

I have used the code below in my `.htaccess` file to redirect to the `index.html`, but it only shows the html content.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.123.123.123
RewriteRule $ /index.html [R=302,L]
```

How can I pull the images and CSS I have in the other folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.123.123.123
RewriteRule ^(images|tools)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html [NC,L,R=302]
```

This will ignore the `images` & `tools` directory but redirect all content to `/maintenance.html`. I also adjusted the format of the `REQUEST_URI` URL as well as the `REMOTE_ADDR` check.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @JakeGould, i try your code but i get a "The page isn't redirecting properly" message. Also I have change maintenance.html to index.html because index.html is the one  i want to use.